# Coq can't infer type parameter in `match`

Tags: math, coq, proof

Consider the following Coq program:

```
Inductive foo : nat -> Type :=
| nil : foo 0
| succ{n:nat} : foo n -> foo n.

Fixpoint bar {n:nat}(A:foo n)(B:foo n) : Prop :=
  match B with
  | nil => False
  | succ C => bar A C
  end.
```

Coq complains on the definition of `bar`:

```
In environment
bar : forall n : nat, foo n -> foo n -> Prop
n : nat
A : foo n
B : foo n
n0 : nat
C : foo n0
The term "C" has type "foo n0" while it is expected to have type "foo n".
```

But for `B : foo n` to be a `succ C`, `C` must also be a `foo n`. Why can't Coq infer this, and how can I fix the definition of `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

When you match on `B`, the type system "forgets" that the new `n'` inside B's type is the same as `n`.  There is a trick to add that information to the context (there are many ways, plugins, etc. but it is good to know how to do it "by hand"). It is called ["The convoy pattern" by Adam Chlipala](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convoy+coq) and every coq user must post a question about that once in his/her life (your's truly included).

You make the body be not just a value but a function that takes an additional input with the type `n=n'` and adds an `eq_refl` term at the end.  This plays well with how Coq's type system can break down terms.

You can either rewrite the `A` type to change its type from `foo n` to `foo n'` with tactics, like this:

```
Fixpoint bar (n:nat) (A:foo n) (B:foo n) : Prop.
  refine (
  match B in (foo m) return  (n=m -> _) with
  | nil => fun _ =>  False
  | @succ n' B' => fun (E : n = n') => bar n' _ B'
  end  eq_refl).
  rewrite E in A.
  apply A.
Defined.
```

or directly with `eq_rect`

```
Fixpoint bar {n:nat} (A:foo n) (B:foo n) : Prop :=
  match B in (foo m) return  (n=m -> _) with
  | nil => fun _ =>  False
  | succ B' => fun E => bar (eq_rect _ _ A _ E) B'
  end  eq_refl.
```